# Google AdSense Duplicate Accounts

Tags: adsense, google-account

[screen I see whenever I try to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoXIq.png)

I try to login and see that screen but I do not have another google account associated with AdSense.  Why does it keep showing this?

Comment: how about checking the box "I confirm I have closed the another account"?  what will happen?

Comment: it will tell me to paste the code into the website again even though I've already done it. Once I click the button to say I did it, it prompts that it is detected even though I never changed anything. Then it says it is setting up again, but later it will do the same thing without ever doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with my clients' website. The issue behind this error is that your website is not fully optimized for Google AdSense. Google keeps updating its algorithm to filter out the ones performing best, if your site isn't performing well, Google will disable your ads, which can lead to disabling your account as well.

There is a video that I am attaching that will help you to get your website completely optimized for AdSense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDMr8MFr5_A

You must follow each and everything mentioned in it carefully. Missing anything will cause you to show same error.